# Why does int value increment to negative and not break given loop?

Tags: java

I was solving Problem 10 of Project Euler, The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28, To find the value of the first triangle number to have over five hundred divisors?

I wrote the following program:

```
public class ProjectEulerProb12HighestDivisorTriangNumb {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int minLim = 7; //As seven is already given in prob statement
    System.out.println(
        "The first triangular no to have more than 500 divisors is " + getNaturalnumb(minLim));
  }

  public static int getNaturalnumb(int natNum) {
    int div = 1, TrianNum = 1;

    while (div <= 500) {
      natNum++;
      TrianNum = getTrianNum(natNum);
      div = getDivCount(TrianNum);
    }

    return TrianNum;
  }

  public static int getTrianNum(int n) { //Generating Triangular Number for any Natural no. n
    int TrianNum = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      TrianNum += i;
    }
    System.out.println(" The current TrianNum is " + TrianNum);
    return TrianNum;
  }

  public static int getDivCount(int n) {// Getting Divisor count for any Triangular no. n

    int DivCount = 1, nextnum = 1;

    while (n != nextnum || DivCount != 500) {
      if (n % nextnum == 0) {
        System.out.println(
            " The current n is "
                + n
                + " Current nextnum is "
                + nextnum
                + " current Divcount is "
                + DivCount);
        DivCount++;
      }

      nextnum++;
    }

    return DivCount;
  }
}
```

I was getting following runtime exception :

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
at ProjectEulerProb12HighestDivisorTriangNumb.getDivCount(ProjectEulerProb12HighestDivisorTriangNumb.java:47)
at ProjectEulerProb12HighestDivisorTriangNumb.getNaturalnumb(ProjectEulerProb12HighestDivisorTriangNumb.java:20)
at ProjectEulerProb12HighestDivisorTriangNumb.main(ProjectEulerProb12HighestDivisorTriangNumb.java:8)
```

To see where I was wrong, I put in print statement in method getDivCount and got following output:

```
    The current TrianNum is 36
    The current n is 36 Current nextnum is 1 current Divcount is 1
    The current n is 36 Current nextnum is 2 current Divcount is 2
    The current n is 36 Current nextnum is 3 current Divcount is 3
    The current n is 36 Current nextnum is 4 current Divcount is 4
    The current n is 36 Current nextnum is 6 current Divcount is 5
    The current n is 36 Current nextnum is 9 current Divcount is 6
    The current n is 36 Current nextnum is 12 current Divcount is 7
    The current n is 36 Current nextnum is 18 current Divcount is 8
    The current n is 36 Current nextnum is 36 current Divcount is 9
    The current n is 36 Current nextnum is -36 current Divcount is 10
    The current n is 36 Current nextnum is -18 current Divcount is 11
    The current n is 36 Current nextnum is -12 current Divcount is 12
    The current n is 36 Current nextnum is -9 current Divcount is 13
    The current n is 36 Current nextnum is -6 current Divcount is 14
    The current n is 36 Current nextnum is -4 current Divcount is 15
    The current n is 36 Current nextnum is -3 current Divcount is 16
    The current n is 36 Current nextnum is -2 current Divcount is 17
    The current n is 36 Current nextnum is -1 current Divcount is 18

    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
```

Why does int value increments to negative after it meets condition (n!=nextnum) ? Help !

Comment: Perhaps you want `while (n!=nextnum && DivCount!=500) `

Comment: Corrected to runtime exception...

Comment: No Eran, a number can have less than 500 divisors and still nextnum can be =n. Also as i need to get first number to have 500 divisors so OR condition.

Comment: @VMi Then you can't expect to break out of the loop when n==nextnum.

Comment: Yes @Codebender, its the latest one.

Comment: @VMi no, it's not. Your main method inputs 7; the 7th triangle number, according to your question is 28; your output shows 36.

Comment: `True || False = True` so you can not break out of loop until both condition are False

Comment: @Andy Turner Because my input no. increments by 1 (becoming 8),  before generating Triangular Number for 8 i.e. 36 (28+8)

Comment: @VMi oh. Well, that's confusing.

Comment: @Sanjeev I believe my loop will break in case any one is true as I used OR  (n = nextnum -> true OR DivCount=500 -> true)

Comment: @VMi No, You whole condition must evaluate to false in order to break the loop

Comment: Thanks @Eran  Made sense finally :) duh ! my bad !

Comment: Thanks @Sanjeev made me realize...thanks !

Comment: Your Most Welcome @VMi .. have fun coding :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are hitting an Integer overflow.

If you run through your loop (for `n = 36`), you will notice that, the `DivCount = 9` when your `nextnum = 36` (ie. `nextnum = n`). This means the loop **does not break** in this iteration.

In all other `nextnum` will **not** be equal to `n` there by going to an infinite loop until your `nextnum` overflows and throws an exception.

Comment: I believe, as per result given above,when DivCount = 6, nextnum is 9 for given triangular number 36.

Comment: @VMi, type correct. When DivCount = 9, nextnum will be 36.

Comment: Agreed..but why isnt breaking the loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment yet, I have to post a answer instead.
I'd like to add: If you need really big numbers, you'll need to work with BigInteger / BigDecimal et cetera - which will also need more difficult code to handle operations. But thats a solution.